How to make Delphi TCXGrid rounded corner?
I want to make my Delphi TcxGrid have rounded corner but don't know how to do.
I researched some codes that make frame rounded, but couldn't find the way making rounded corner on cxGrid.
Is there any component or procedure to make it?

Post a Devexpress support ticket. I see no hits yet: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/list?searchString=tcxgrid%20rounded%20corner&sorting=Relevance
